# How to use arquillian rest extension with mockito

Tags: mockito, jboss-arquillian

Hope you can help me out with something I've been struggling with for some time now. I'm using arquillian for my integraton testing and it works very nice. So I thought instead of testing my persistence layer I wanted to isolate my rest services layer to test it also. This time using arquillian, the arquillian rest extension (http://arquillian.org/modules/rest-extension/) which sounds perfect for black box testing of my services layer and combine this with mockito.

My application exists of several layers from top to bottom:

- ui (javascript)
- interaction layer (Rest services using resteasy)
- business layer (Stateless EJBs)
- persistence layer (DAOs)

All gets deployed in a java ee6 container and uses that technology.

In order to test the interaction layer which holds the rest services I'm using arquillian rest extension which avoids the hassle of setting up a httpclient in my code and invoking the rest call. This all is done by using arquillian rest extension which sounds great doesn't it!?

My rest services have several CDI beans injected which represent the business layer. In order to avoid having to test all layers at once, I want the rest layer to be isolated using mocks. So I tried to use mockito that could mock the injected beans in the rest layer. Unfortunately my mocks work in my test, but the mocks are not inserted in my rest services.

In order to fix this I stumpled upon another arquillian extension called autodiscover but have no clue what to do or configure in order to let the mocks work in my project.

hope you guys can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

In fact when running **black box** tests like rest calls or selenium based tests either mockito neither autodiscover or even [byteman extension](https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-extension-byteman) will help you cause your tests are driven *outside* the container and you can relay only on what was deployed.

One alternative is to deploy fake services so for example if you have a rest endpoint like this:

```
   @Path("rest")  
   public void MyEndpoint{
      @Inject 
      RealService realService;

      @Path("rest-resource")
      @GET
      public Response methodUnderTest(){
         realService.doSomething();
         return Response.ok().build();
      }
}
```

on your test **@Deployment** you can add a *FakeService* instead of *RealService* where the FakeService is either a CDI alternative or a Bean Specialization, i have wrote about arquillian and mocks on my blog, you can [read the post here](https://rpestano.wordpress.com/2014/10/25/arquillian-and-mocks/).